# HTML Tables - how can I make all cells other than the last always be wide enough?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>someArg:String</td>
            <td>&ndash;</td>
            <td>This is a description about this argument.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table is set to 100% width using CSS and is dynamic based on the browser width.

When the third cell has a small amount of content, the first cell will all be on one line. However, when the third cell contains a lot of content, the first cell will crumple up and may look like this:

`someArg:`
`String`

I want to ensure that the content of the first column always stretches its cell to fit perfectly (for the widest first cell in the table obviously, not individually).

From here I just want the final cell in the row to use up the remainder of the table's 100% width.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CHMv/) for more explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/8CHMv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a class to the td that you want to be one line and add

```
.myClass{
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the nowrap element to your HTML TD tag.

Answer (score 2):

`<td nowrap="nowrap">` from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps set the white space: nowrap property in CSS in the first to as a CSS class?

Details on the nowrap here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas:

1. If the content of the first column is almost the same, just give a fixed width to the first column. and leave the third column have no width set.
2. If the content of the first column has big difference, set

   `white-space: nowrap;`

with css to it.